# What does an empty map of interfaces do in a golang function?

Tags: go

I was reading through [an article on golang templates](https://elithrar.github.io/article/approximating-html-template-inheritance/) and this came up in the example code.

```
func renderTemplate(w http.ResponseWriter, name string, data map[string]interface{}) error {
    // Ensure the template exists in the map.
    tmpl, ok := templates[name]
    if !ok {
        return fmt.Errorf("The template %s does not exist.", name)
    }

    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "text/html; charset=utf-8")
    tmpl.ExecuteTemplate(w, "base", data)

    return nil
}
```

The part that I don't understand is the parameter `data` in the function declaration:

```
data map[string]interface{}
```

I only have a very basic understanding of interfaces in go, but I have no idea why it would be used in this way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`interface{}` is like `(void*)` in C or `Object` in Java, it means that a value of any type can be stored in the map.

Comment: But looking at the code doesn't `data` just stay empty? Why not pass in `nil`?

Comment: What makes you think it's empty when it's being provided by the caller?

Comment: :O I have no idea how I missed that. Thank you haha

Comment: Can I also assume that whoever wrote the code made a small mistake? They are passing in data, which is a map, as the third parameter to ExecuteTemplate, but in the docs it's not a map it is just `data interface{}`.

Comment: No. `interface{}` is again being used as a pointer-to-anything. The template API lets you pass arbitrary objects and it will use reflection to figure out what its fields are. Using a map instead lets the set of fields be dynamic, which is needed because the template being used is also dynamic.

Comment: As the author of that article: @ChristopherCurrie is correct. Further, the reason we pass in a `map[string]interface{}` is so we can *name* our data as we pass it to the template and then refer to it by name in the template itself - sometimes that might be `.user`, other times it might be `.post`, etc.

Comment: @elithrar thank you for responding. I'm very new to go, and your article saved me from getting `mustache` or even `gorazor`

Comment: There is a difference between `void*` in C and `interface{}` in Go though: you can use pass by reference semantics with `interface{}`: http://play.golang.org/p/vZdaQrYPU9